# Monitor ELB and check if it has a traffic within 2 weeks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elb, aws-elb

I have a list of Load balancers and want to check if it has a traffic for more than 2 weeks with the help of aws cli.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Can you please re-phrase your question ? Can't really understand what you are looking for.

Comment: i have a list of the loadbalancer from that i have to check if the loadbalacer is used in last 2 week or not (like any traffic has passed or not) so how can i do it with aws cli. @ben5556

Comment: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html. Fetch stats from a metric like ProcessedBytes or RequestCount as shown here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html to check whether your ELB processed any traffic or not